# Is there any way to load an image from google drive into the cuda code running on colab?

Tags: c++, image, google-colaboratory, drive

I am trying out cuda programming on colab.I tried with basic numeric array operations on cuda kernel.
For running cuda on colab I can see a lot of examples on net.

```
!apt update -qq;
!wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb;
!dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb;
!apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/7fa2af80.pub;
!apt-get update -qq;
!apt-get install cuda gcc-5 g++-5 -y -qq;
!ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-5 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc;
!ln -s /usr/bin/g++-5 /usr/local/cuda/bin/g++;
!apt install cuda-8.0;
!/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version
!pip install git+git://github.com/andreinechaev/nvcc4jupyter.git
%load_ext nvcc_plugin

%%cu
#include <stdio.h>
#define N  64
inline cudaError_t checkCudaErr(cudaError_t err, const char* msg) {
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CUDA Runtime error at %s: %s\n", msg, cudaGetErrorString(err));
  }
  return err;
}
__global__ void matrixMulGPU( int * a, int * b, int * c )
{
  /*
   * Build out this kernel.
   */
    int row = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int col = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int val = 0;
    if (row < N && col < N) {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
         val += a[row * N + i] * b[i * N + col];
       }

      c[row * N + col] = val;
    }
}
/*
 * This CPU function already works, and will run to create a solution matrix
 * against which to verify your work building out the matrixMulGPU kernel.
 */
void matrixMulCPU( int * a, int * b, int * c )
{
  int val = 0;for( int row = 0; row < N; ++row )
    for( int col = 0; col < N; ++col )
    {
      val = 0;
      for ( int k = 0; k < N; ++k )
        val += a[row * N + k] * b[k * N + col];
      c[row * N + col] = val;
    }
}
int main()
{
  int *a, *b, *c_cpu, *c_gpu; // Allocate a solution matrix for both the CPU and the GPU operations
 int size = N * N * sizeof (int); // Number of bytes of an N x N matrix// Allocate memory
  cudaMallocManaged (&a, size);
  cudaMallocManaged (&b, size);
  cudaMallocManaged (&c_cpu, size);
  cudaMallocManaged (&c_gpu, size);// Initialize memory; create 2D matrices
 from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
PATH_OF_DATA= '/content/gdrive/"My Drive"/sherry-christian-8Myh76_3M2U-unsplash'

  for( int row = 0; row < N; ++row )
    for( int col = 0; col < N; ++col )
    {
      a[row*N + col] = row;
      b[row*N + col] = col+2;
      c_cpu[row*N + col] = 0;
      c_gpu[row*N + col] = 0;
    }/*
   * Assign `threads_per_block` and `number_of_blocks` 2D values
   * that can be used in matrixMulGPU above.
   */dim3 threads_per_block(32, 32, 1);
  dim3 number_of_blocks(N / threads_per_block.x + 1, N / threads_per_block.y + 1, 1);
  printf("%d",number_of_blocks);
 matrixMulGPU <<< number_of_blocks, threads_per_block >>> ( a, b, c_gpu );
 checkCudaErr(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), "Syncronization");
 checkCudaErr(cudaGetLastError(), "GPU");// Call the CPU version to check our work
  matrixMulCPU( a, b, c_cpu );// Compare the two answers to make sure they are equal
  bool error = false;
  for( int row = 0; row < N && !error; ++row )
    for( int col = 0; col < N && !error; ++col )
      if (c_cpu[row * N + col] != c_gpu[row * N + col])
      {
        printf("FOUND ERROR at c[%d][%d]\n", row, col);
        error = true;
        break;
      }
if (!error)
    printf("Success!\n");// Free all our allocated memory
  cudaFree(a); cudaFree(b);
  cudaFree( c_cpu ); cudaFree( c_gpu );
}
```

This is a sample code.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
PATH_OF_DATA= '/content/gdrive/"My Drive"/sherry-christian-8Myh76_3M2U-unsplash'
```

I know these lines are wrong.I am using python snippet in a c++ code.I want to use a c++ snippet instead.

I want to load an image into the cuda c++ program and try out operations.So is there any way to load an image from drive to cuda c++ program on google colab.Can anyone help me out with the sample code ?

Comment: What happened when you tried? Please show your code. [mcve] Note the at StackOverflow if you don't show your work / attempt to solve the problem you usually don't get help.

Comment: you would require the compiler nvcc, do you know how to access that in colab environment? As far I knew you would only get Python libraries with GPU build.

Comment: @drescherjm I am getting cuda enviroinment through installing cuda libraries on colab.

Comment: If are really asking whether there is a C++ Google drive API, I am pretty sure the answer is no. I also don't see what this has to do with CUDA, I have removed the tag twice. Please don't re-add it again.

Comment: @talonmies thanks for your reply.The reason I have added CUDA is this is a cuda code compiled with nvcc compiler on google drive .

Comment: Yes but that is basically irrelevant to your question. I would suggest your best option would be to use the Python API for Google drive and then use a CUDA capable Python API for pushing code and data to the GPU

Comment: thanks for your reply @talonmies.